# TApplicationException: Internal error processing getFormType in Apache Zeppelin

Tags: python, apache, apache-zeppelin

I am totally new to Apache Zeppelin. Here is what I did on that.

1) Open a new note.
2) Type the following code. (Uses python kernel in Apache Zeppelin)

```
%python
a = 2+3
```

3) In the output it shows the following error.

```
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing getFormType
    at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:111)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_getFormType(RemoteInterpreterService.java:337)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.getFormType(RemoteInterpreterService.java:323)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:446)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:111)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:387)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to know what is wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.